# Application crashes after clearing storage with error code 14 SQLITE_CANTOPEN: Could not open database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

After clearing application storage & cache, started getting unknown error **(code 14 SQLITE_CANTOPEN): Could not open database**. Before clearing storage, everything was working properly, both Emulator and Device.

I tried deleting application from Emulator, wiped Emulator and cleaned project, but still crashing when opening MainActivity. For the sake of problem solving, I've put writing permissions in AndroidManifest but still the same error.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Instead of doing

```
this.baza_putanja = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + "databases/";
```

I did

```
baza_putanja = context.getDatabasePath(baza_ime).getPath();
```

What bothers me is if I'm trying to open database using a path that does not include the database name - *why was it working before clearing application storage & cache?*

**BazaPodatakaHelper.java**

```
    private String baza_putanja = null;
    private static final String baza_ime = "eng_dictionary.db";
    private SQLiteDatabase econDictionary;
    private final Context mContext;

    public BazaPodatakaHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, baza_ime, null, 1);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.baza_putanja = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + "databases/";
        Log.e("Putanja 1", baza_putanja);
    }

public void kreirajBazuPodataka() throws IOException {

        boolean bazaPodatakaPostoji = provjeriBazuPodataka();
        if ( !bazaPodatakaPostoji ) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                kopirajBazuPodataka();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Greška prilikom kopiranja baze podataka");
            }
        }
    }

public boolean provjeriBazuPodataka() {

        SQLiteDatabase provjera;

        try {
            String putanja = baza_putanja + baza_ime;
            provjera = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(putanja, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            throw new Error("Greška prilikom provjeravanja baze podataka");
        }

        if (provjera != null) {
            provjera.close();
        }

        return provjera != null;
    }
```

**Error Log:**

```
2019-07-17 20:39:30.482 7885-7885/com.benjaminkljn.econdictionary E/Putanja 1: /data/data/com.benjaminkljn.econdictionary/assets/ 2019-07-17 20:39:30.485 7885-7885/com.benjaminkljn.econdictionary E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 36683 of [c255889bd9] 2019-07-17 20:39:30.485 7885-7885/com.benjaminkljn.econdictionary E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:36683: (2) open(/data/data/com.benjaminkljn.econdictionary/assets/eng_dictionary.db)
-  2019-07-17 20:39:30.491 7885-7885/com.benjaminkljn.econdictionary E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/data/com.benjaminkljn.econdictionary/assets/eng_dictionary.db'.
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14 SQLITE_CANTOPEN): Could not open database
```

Comment: u need not necessarily put data in public storage

Comment: @HarKal As I've said, current database and path was working fine until I've cleaned application storage & cache. Before that, I've tested everything and was working properly.

Comment: well that was just a recommendation from my side as u would not have to take storage writing permission at all. and still be able to store data.

Comment: and another recommendation that i would give u is use android Room lib

Comment: @HarKal It was working without writing permissions. What would be better way for storing database?

Comment: and as far as ur problem is concerned it has occurred due to malformed data being inserted in db so u try deleting all the data manually

Comment: @HarKal Data from database itself? Also, thanks for recommendation.

Comment: there is a file manager in android studio use that to erase ur DBs

Comment: @HarKal I've deleted and re-imported database, but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is saying

```
/data/data/com.benjaminkljn.econdictionary/assets/eng_dictionary.db
```

Your code above does not include **assets** in the path, so your issue is probably based around that.

Typically, and specifically, if using `context.getDatabasePath(your_database)`, the attempt would be to open

```
/data/data/com.benjaminkljn.econdictionary/databases/eng_dictionary.db
```

- i.e. the **databases** folder not the **assets**.

Additionally in your comments you mention :-

```
>I've deleted and re-imported database
```

Typically, importing the database, at least for an App, would be copying the database to be imported (included with the app) to the **assets** folder.

As such it could be that you are trying to open the database from what you think is the assets folder, but you cannot use the included/imported assets folder directly as the assets are managed by **AssetsManager**.

You could probably use Device Explorer to create the **assets** folder in /data/data/com.benjaminkljn.econdictionary and then copy the database into that folder and then the open may then work.

If you did that previously then, after deleting/uninstalling the App would, if the database hasn't been manually copied into the assets folder (and thus the assets folder has be created), result in the issue you have encountered.

- When an App is installed the /data/data/com.benjaminkljn.econdictionary folder will be created but not the sub folders **databases** not the sub folder named **assets**, Clearing the App's storage effectively returns to this point.

However, manually copying the database, will only work for the specific App. It wouldn't work if you published the App, as you would not have access to copy the file manually.

To use a pre-existing database in an App then the recommended way is to :-

1. Create the App or part of the App
2. Create the **assets** folder in main/src/ (same location as where the res/java folders and android.manaifest are located).

   1. **Note** if using SQLiteAssetHelper then create the **databases** folder in the **assets** folder.
3. Copy the database into the **assets**
4. The App should then before attempting to use the database, copy the database from the assets folder, accessing the database using AssetManager, into the location from which the database will be accessed.

   1. Typically this location is /data/data/the_package_name/databases/your_database
   2. The reliable/recommended way of determening the location is to use context.getDatabasePath(your_database).
   3. Note that the **databases** folder will not exist for a new App and must be created (SQLiteAssethelper will do this).

[SQliteAssethelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/blob/master/README.markdown) simplifies this.

Comment: Still not sure why would deleting the folder and creating it again fix my issue, but I'm glad it's solved. I did use Device Explorer to copy database into assets folder, but still was getting same unknown error. Though, thanks for tip about manually copying database. I just need to extend class above with SQLiteAssetHelper and provide constructor with a database name/version?

Comment: @BenjaminKljuno yes making sure that you **don't** use Device Explorer to copy the database BUT that the database is copied into the assets/databases folder (which you may have to create) of the AS project. It is than packaged with the App and SQLiteAssethelper will copy the file into the App's data/data/.../databases folder.